# How to express HAVING in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, having

How does one express in LINQ the SQL HAVING clause?

I'm looking for duplicates.

```
SELECT AssetId, COUNT(*) FROM ASSET GROUP BY AssetName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If there's no special syntax and the answer is stacked queries just say so in as many words.

Comment: This sounds like a Where() could do it.

Comment: A HAVING is just  WHERE applied following the GROUP-BY instead of ahead of it, acting on the post-grouped data instead of the pre-grouped data.

Comment: The scope of clauses in LINQ and the implications of their position is something with which I'm still coming to grips. In SQL you are obliged to use the HAVING clause to gain appropriate scope.

Comment: @bbill - Of course you're right, but that represents not one but *two* departures from the scope of my question, which is whether there is LINQ syntax directly equivalent to HAVING, rather than querying at large. I appreciate that you were trying to expedite my purpose, but in this case my purpose is to learn about LINQ syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    from asset in MyAssetTable
    group asset by asset.AssetName into AssetNames
    where AssetNames.Count() > 1
    select new { AssetNames.Key, AssetNames.Count() }
```

Comment: asset does not exist in the context of the select statement.

Comment: Had to fix your select clause but this works so congrats, you get the tick.

Comment: Christopher, true but remember the exercise was to learn LINQ syntax for applying conditions to domain aggregations without nesting queries. I just simplified the select clause so it would run. Note above I have rewritten select to retrieve asset.Id and the count. I was happy with just asset because I knew which ones ought to be returned; this is how I knew he'd nailed it.